# Can't display map on template using PointField django

Tags: python, django, forms, dictionary, geodjango

Can we display a map on a template using django `PointField`?

I have a model with one `PointField` and then after creating a model form, I want to display the map in my template using that form.

View

```
def map_view(request):
    form = ShopForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'ads/map.html', context)
```

Template

```
      <html>
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>
       <div>
       <form method="post">
      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" >
      </form>
      </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

I was wondering is it possible to display the map using that or do I need to something extra.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same question and thankfully I got the right way of doing it.

Anyone who's facing this issue can follow this [link](https://medium.com/@h4k1m0u/displaying-a-map-in-a-django-webapp-1-3-creating-a-gis-database-with-postgresql-and-postgis-e596d3c2310)

The tutorial is divided into three parts.

REMEMBER:

When you reach to the 2nd part and everything is done and you're writing **python manage.py runserver**

-in your template include all these

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% leaflet_css %}
{% leaflet_js %}
```

Place this within  your `{% block content %}` `{% endblock content %}` otherwise you'll end up rendering nothing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following part of the documentation on your form?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#widget-classes:

> ```
> from django.contrib.gis import forms
>
> class ShopForm(forms.Form):
>     point = forms.PointField(widget=
>         forms.OSMWidget(attrs={'map_width': 800, 'map_height': 500})
>     )
> ```